# Determine the feature dataset of a layer in an Esri file geodatabase

Tags: python, layers, ogr, file-geodatabase, feature-dataset

I have an Esri file geodatabase with a single feature dataset.

Using `ogr` and `python`

```
ds = ogr.Open('myfile.gdb')

for i in range(ds.GetLayerCount()):
    layer = ds.GetLayerByIndex(i)
```

I can iterate the layers of the GDB file.

While using `ogr` and `python` how can I determine which feature dataset the layer belongs to?

---

Looking at the GDAL/OGR [API](https://gdal.org/python/) I haven't found anything.

The driver [description](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/filegdb.html) only mentions how to create a layer in a specific feature dataset.

[This](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/300651/get-path-of-feature-classes-in-feature-datasets-without-arcpy) has an idea, but I hope for a more simple way to do it.

Comment: Esri's Feature Dataset is not supported in OGR. You would have to use an Esri python extension, arcpy, to do what you are asking.